# Custom View Helper is never run when extending Zend_Form_Element_File

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

I want my own form element based on Zend_Form_Element_File.
My Problem: the custom view helper I created is never run. Instead, always the FormFile Viewhelper is run.
When I inherit from Zend_Form_Element_Xhtml, my custom view helper works.

Does not work:

```
class XY_Model_Form_Imageu extends Zend_Form_Element_File
{
  public $helper = "imageUpload";
}
```

Does work, but I don't want to do the file upload on my own:

```
class XY_Model_Form_Imageu extends Zend_Form_Element_Xhtml
{
  public $helper = "imageUpload";
}
```

Any ideas? I'm using ZF 1.10.

EDIT:
It seems like if it's this issue: http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-8136

Does anybody has a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the workaround was that I created custom decorator which I used in the extended file element.

The decorator's render() has been overloaded to use the view helper I needed.
The view helper's function is hardcoded in the decorator as the bug report says, which is a shame...

Comment: You should look at my post that I linked to.  It turns out it wasn't so hard to do once I knew about the `'placement' => false` option.